# dblink_build_sql_delete . I need to be able to delete the data with <= condition

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

```
SELECT xyz.*
FROM PUBLIC.DBLINK ('dbname=LiveDB port=5432 host=127.0.0.1 user=postgres 
password=root','SELECT dblink_build_sql_delete(''"folderstatus"'', ''1'', 1, 
''{"1"}'')')
as xyz (id int);

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "DELETE FROM folderstatuslu WHERE 
id = '1'"
```

I'm unable to delete the record here. I also need to know how to add a "<=" condition and also need to pass a parameter. 
My code will be like this, I'll be selecting the max(colum_value) into a variable and pass it to the above query and should be able to delete like below.

```
DELETE FROM folderstatuslu WHERE id <= '1'  --> (in the place of 1, I will 
pass a variable.)
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just dblink and format?..

```
t=# create table so43 (i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into so43 select 1;
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from dblink('dbname = t',format('delete from so43 where i <= %s',1)) as row(result text);
  result
----------
 DELETE 1
(1 row)
```

Comment: Yay!! this looks good, Vaso. Later I tried with dblink_exec, it also worked for me. Thanks anyways. !!